# Rails3 model associations with has_many :through fails with NameError

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord, naming-conventions

I want to associate two models (Team and Member) by has_many :through, but returns NameError.
What am I missing?

## Models

```
class Team < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :team_members
  has_many :members, :through => :team_members
end

class Member < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :team_members
  has_many :teams, :through => :team_members
end

class TeamMember < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :teams
  belongs_to :members
end
```

## Database Tables

```
teams
members
teams_members
```

## Errors

When I try to create new record with association, I got following errors.

```
@team = Team.new
@team.members
NameError: uninitialized constant Team::Members
```

Also when searching for existing record, these errors are thrown.

```
@team = Team.find(1)
@team.members # expecting to get existing records in members table
NameError: uninitialized constant Team::Members
```

Comment: Shouldn't the belongs_to associations be *singular*? ie `belongs_to :team, belongs_to :member`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The correct name for TeamMember table is team_members not teams_members

Comment: Thanks! Now everything is running as expected.